# When using popover segue, does not allow controls added to viewcontroler to display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I would like to take advantage of using the PopOver segue now available in Xcode 6. I have been experimenting with this, seems very straightforward. However when i add any type of control, label, or any element, and run the project in the simulator, the added elements (controls, labels, etc) do not display. I am running iOS 8.1.2 and using xCode 6, objective-c. The application is targeted for iPad. 
I am going from a standard viewcontrler to a viewcontrler,

When i do a standard modal segue, everything is visible.

thanks in advance for any help,

Steve

links to screen shot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/93wt2twuuccbuji/main%20storyboard%20image.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/im4bzlrnrov43cp/from%20simulator.png?dl=0

Comment: Post some screen shots of the issue if possible.

Comment: i was not able to post image to the system. i have included some links to my dropbox

Answer (score 0):

did you give the anchor point in storyboard?if you want to display second view controller on pressing a button give the anchor point to that button.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean by giving the giving the anchor point to the button.

Comment: select the popover segue in storyboard and check attribute inspector.There is an option called anchor. Right click the button from previous page and drop it on anchor option.It will give the reference.